# javascript regex: matching a phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

how do I match this phone number in Javascript?

```
> str
"(555) 555-3300"
> str.match( '/\(555\) 555-3300/gi/' )
null
> str.match( '/(555) 555-3300/gi/' )
null
```

I bet someone can answer this in 2 seconds. Googling the problem didn't help me.

### Update

Also tried without the quotes:

```
str.match(/\(555\) 555-3300/gi/)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

---

Ultimately I'm trying to replace the phone number with a different one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lose the quotes:

```
str.match(/\(480\) 945-3300/g)
```

Comment: John's answer correctly defines a regex to match that string - though I'd point out that if you want to /exactly/ match the string, you may as well use indexOf(): if (str.indexOf("(480) 945-3300") !== -1) { /* string matches */ }

Comment: Tried that as well: `str.match(/\(480\) 945-3300/gi/)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: stackoverflow didn't format my backlashes to escape the parens in the last comment, but i did put them in.

Comment: With the flags it'd be `str.match(/\(480\) 945-3300/gi)` -- get rid of that trailing slash.

Comment: nevermind, i have to double-escape the parens: `new RegExp('\\(480\\) 555-5555')`